# Can't save my photos from bricked phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, boot-loop, twrp

My unrooted phone is stuck on Samsung logo. I have TWRP. I backup now and restore but it still does the same. I have photos in the phone. How can I save them?

Comment: Boot into TWRP, mount the /data or external SD card if the photos are there, then pull them using MTP or ADB.

Comment: @Firelord how do I sir?

Comment: No need to be so formal, Jeremy. You need to find a way to setup ADB in PC and make [tag:ADB] detect the device. Start from [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474) Then boot the device into TWRP, connect it into PC, launch a shell on PC and do `adb pull`. Search the web and you would know the complete idea. Otherwise, see if device is getting detected as a portable media player or something when booted into TWRP.

Comment: Samsung phones don't come with TWRP , they have a stock recovery.To install TWRP, you need to be rooted. Unless the phone was previously rooted and root removed now? Please check the root status using apps on play store..search for root checker

Comment: @beeshyams Are you sure about the *To install TWRP, you need to be rooted.* part? Because I as far as I know root is not needed to flash a custom recovery?

Comment: @SarpSTA.  You are right, it is not mandatory . Should have said probably, since one doesn't normally flash TWRP, except to flash ROM, on Samsung for fear of tripping Knox and of course losing updates. Technically, you are correct and thanks for that, but my gut feeling is that it is rooted, and definitely not right to express it as a sure thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have access to your recovery it means you are not bricked. Far as I understand from what your say is that it is a bootloop. I don't know what caused it but if you want to save your photos there are multiple ways of doing it. I will suggest adb (as I was typing this, so did [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord)) Having access to TWRP means you can use adb. Use `adb pull` to pull DCIM folder in `sdcard` to have photos your camera took and other folders you need.

Comment: how will I fix my phone after this sir?

Comment: @JeremyC Depends. That's too long to answer in comments. Try asking another question.

Comment: i was rooted but i did factory reset

Comment: @beeshyams was right obviously then. You are still rooted since factory reset doesn't unroot your phone.